# linking zoltan under trillinos and as stand alone

Tags: load-balancing, partitioning, trilinos

I am trying to call SANDIA's zoltan and perform load balancing
When I link to the zoltan library as a stand alone static library it works fine
but when I link to the same library under Trillinos, (not my preference, as per cluster administrator). it gives the following error:

```
[ 1] openmpi-2.0.1/lib/libmpi.so.20(MPI_Allreduce+0x80)[0x7f2d9aa974e0]
 [ 2] (Zoltan_Create+0x5a3)[0x53bdc3]
```

even the first step, which is creating zoltan function fails.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very annoying problem, and all happened due to the laziness of the cluster admin, refusing to install zoltan and implying that he has already installed trillinos and I should go ahead and link to that library. FALSE, this will give a lot of unnecessary headache as it is hard to detect, if you are getting the any errors in the "zoltan_create(MPI_COMM)" stage, check to see if you have linked the appropriate library. And yes, insist the admin to install what you need